# Don´t fire until Ajax is done

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I´m working on an app using PhoneGap, JQuery

I have 2 standard javascript functions.

`LoadLanguage()` will make an Ajax call to get a language file and then set up a Javascript object.

SetLanguage() will use the previous object (set in LoadLanguage()) and then set some variables with the correct language.

So in my js file i have this code:

```
function LoadLanguage()
{
    ....make ajax call and set up an object
}

function SetLanguage()
{
    ....set language based of previous LoadLanguage()
}

$( '#startpage' ).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event)
{
    LoadLanguage();
    ....
}

$( '#startpage' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event)
{
    SetLanguage();
    ....
}
```

Problem is that the `SetLanguage()` will fire before `LoadLanguage()` is done. I could solve this problem running `SetLanguage()` inside the `LoadLanguage ajax.complete`. But this is not good since i need to call `SetLanguage()` in other parts of my code.

So how do i solve this in a good way?

Comment: Because ajax is asynchronous the only method is as you have identified using it as a callback in the `ajax.complete` function. You can still call `SetLanguage()` in other parts of the code as long as it is in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the SetLanguage() function once the ajax request is completed and response is received. 
if you are using jquery then in LoadLanguage function where you are making ajax request

```
success: function(response)
{
    SetLanguage();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i used it like that...but didn´t read you post until know. But you will get the "Accepted answer tick". Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set async property of ajax call to false. This might be helpful: [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

Comment: I would advise against this, ask yourself why are you using AJAX? See  [When is it appropriate to use synchronous ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316488/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-synchronous-ajax) For more info

Comment: false will be removed in JQuery 1.8 so i don´t want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are proposing seems fine to me. Your question - or more precisely, your point of interest seems to be language agnostic.

As I understand it, you believe there is an issue around calling the `SetLanugage` function from other parts of your script, and also after the `LoadLanguage` function. I don't see an issue here at all. If it is safe to call `SetLanguage` from other parts of the script, then after loading a language, it should behave the same.

Comment: It wasn´t really an issue. I messed around with it a little more then it had to be. But thx for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also set a global variable outside of your function calls that will only become true when the language has been loaded. Then test for this inside SetLanguage.

Comment: I could do that. But it doesn´t seem like a nice solution. Because if it else false. I need to take care of it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to  lock down the ajax call use this

```
if($.active){ 
  //there's an ajax function running
}else{ 
  //there's no ajax function running
}
```