# JavaScript setInterval only runs once

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, timer, setinterval

I am attempting to have an HTML page update a textarea with content from a text file every second, using JavaScript's setInterval function. However, the function inside the setInterval call only seems to run once.

**Javascript:**

```
// Send a GET request to the given location
function sendRequest(location, nonblocking) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", location, nonblocking);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
}

// Refresh the communication log
function refreshLog() {
     document.getElementById("comm_log").value = sendRequest("src/log.txt", false);
}

window.setInterval(refreshLog, 1000);
```

The request is not asynchronous simply because the text file will never be long, and this is something I am trying to throw together quickly.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
    width: 98%;
    height: 80%;
    resize: none;
    font-family: "Courier New";
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="src/script.js"></script>

</head>

...

<textarea id="comm_log" readonly></textarea>

...

</html>
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Any error showing up in your console?

Comment: Please don't do this. Not just AJAX, JavaScript itself is an event-based, asynchronous language. Don't try to circumvent it for convenience.

Comment: It should work, did you try putting logs in refreshLog function? Or something wrong with ajax call?

Comment: Why are you doing synchronous AJAX? That's blocking and generally bad practice, on how to avoid it see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593)

Comment: In a related note, the only time where it may be defensible to use synchronous AJAX is [during onbeforeunload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316488/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-synchronous-ajax).

Comment: @voithos Do you have a suggestion for how to only reload the textarea when the content in the .txt changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose your browser is caching. You get the data exactly once and then the next requests are served from cache. So the `refreshLog` should be called repeatedly, just the following calls won't have any effect on the page as it's serving from cache.

Append to the URL some unique part like a `?=<timestamp>`.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", location + '?=' + new Date().getTime(), nonblocking);
```

Comment: This did the trick. I will be changing to an async request based on the comments, but I suspect I would have had this issue with an async request as well. I will accept the answer as soon as SO lets me. Thanks!

Comment: @alexgerst You would, but you could prevent the browser from caching by having your response come back with no-cache headers.

Comment: Which god ? There are at least 5000 different ones.