# In Ajax, why allow synchronous operation?

Tags: ajax

As Ajax stands, I believe it is made available to make asynchronous call to server but why does it also allow to be set to synchronous as an option?

What would be the case when you want synchronous operation using Ajax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to use synchronous ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316488/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-synchronous-ajax)

Comment: I bet you're talking about the `async` option of `jQuery.ajax()`?

Comment: @sp00m it's probably not jQuery. I saw it from my book example that take boolean parameter for switching over async or sync.

Comment: AJAX is a name for a technique that builds on top of the XMLHttpRequest object – and that provides the option to switch between async or sync. Yes, AJAX is mostly used asynchronously, because otherwise the browser’s UI would get block for as long as the request runs – but there are some special use cases where a synchronous request may have its benefits.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX predates many of the libraries, extensions, and languages we currently use for handling asynchronous interactions between client and server. Initially, deferred handling of a response was not easily accomplished on the client, so the design of AJAX allowed for the developer to indicate that some operations should wait for response by executing synchronously.

The ability to operate synchronously is still included in AJAX to maintain legacy code. It is really difficult to come up with a use case today that would require the use of a synchronous AJAX call.