# window.onbeforeunload, closing browser and synchronous AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronous, onbeforeunload

I've been searching for any reasonable example of a situation, when synchronous AJAX makes sense. I've found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316512/769384), where the author mentions `window.onbeforeunload` and claims, that "the request would never stop" if the AJAX call was asynchronous.

Can anybody explain this? I mean - `window.onbeforeunload` is fired when the user wants to close the tab. What had to be going on to make the tab still alive, even though somebody clicked to close it? Can somebody give more specific example?

Comment: The browser closes the window and any requests that are fired from it will die. Nick Craver is saying that in his post. Synchronous `httpRequest` in `beforeunload` will halt script execution, preventing the unload to happen until the request has been resolved.

Comment: @Mouser Ah, I think I got it. So when the user clicks "close window", the `beforeunload` event is fired. It contains some AJAX call. In case of asynchronous, the call will be fired, it's success callback is delayed until the server response arrives and script will carry on and die immediately. In case of synchronous AJAX, the entire script is freezed to make sure that the response arrives and then the window dies safely. Is that right?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: Exactly correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He didn't say the request will never *stop*; he said it will never *complete*. That is, your code has no hope of ever getting the response back, because the execution environment (the window) would disappear from existence before that happened.

The tab will close when `window.onbeforeunload` exits with a truthy value. Thus, as long as it is running, the page is waiting for the return value, and not closing. This allows a synchronous AJAX to be sent, and for the response to be received and processed. If the request is asynchronous, the code constructs XHR object, then exits, and the page (and your code) goes away.

I have never tested this, but the answerer apparently believes (and I don't think it unreasonable) that the page might not stick around long enough for an async XHR to even be *sent*, let alone to receive a response. Thus, if you want to be sure the server receives the information that the user closed the page, you want to have the request synchronous.

Comment: that was difficult, but I finally got it. But can you give any real-life example of that? What AJAX call do I need to fire when closing a tab, assuming that I have to get the response back from the server?

Comment: What AJAX call you need to fire? I don't know. If you created a forum, you might want to track "online users", and take the user off the list when he closes your window. If you were a serial killer, you might remotely trigger a bomb when the user closes your window. Depends on your application. (Disclaimer: I do not condone triggering bombs from `onbeforeunload`. Don't do it.)

Answer (score 0):

> What had to be going on to make the tab still alive, even though somebody clicked to close it? Can somebody give more specific example?

Sending a synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` on unload is the only way to guarantee delivery of session data when a user-agent unloads the page (and may never re-visit your site again). There are two specific cases for this:

1. **Tracking** - Tracking and reporting the total session time for a user's page visit.
2. **Batching** - Coalescing and deferring delivery of batched session data to reduce the number of server requests.

The [Beacon spec](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/) (`navigator.sendBeacon`) was designed to optimize this specific case, making it possible to send asynchronous requests guaranteed to still complete even after the page unloads.