# Ajax XML causing potential memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, memory-leaks

I have a timer firing off every couple minutes to update a piece of info in the DOM.  In Chrome developer tools I'm seeing memory increases after every call and by doing a Heap profile I found detached DOM tree.  Did I miss something in my code?

```
function update() {
    var preferredName;
    var url = '/foo?bar=1';
    var xml = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: url,
        dataType: 'xml'
    });
    $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
        preferredName = $(this).find("value").text();
    });

    $('#name').text(preferredName);
}
```

Comment: **Typo:** single quote required after `dataType: 'xml`.

Comment: `async: false` this is almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: An interesting read on your issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364992/how-synchronous-ajax-call-could-cause-memory-leak.