# javascript code to count folders in a directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajax code is given below

```
function countFolder(){
    var dir='albums';
    var count=0;
    alert(dir);

    $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        async:false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a:contains(" + 'album' + ")").each(function () {// function to read foldera name contains 'album'
                count++;
                //alert(url);
            });
        }
    });

    return count;
}
```

Is there any equalent code for pure javascript?

Comment: Splitting hairs, that *is* JavaScript code. You probably want the same functionality but without using jQuery? (Note that you can't do it without AJAX. JavaScript by itself doesn't have access to the file system.)

Comment: This may help you: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/

Comment: Do not use synchronous JAX.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: [What are the drawbacks of using synchronous ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517403/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-using-synchronous-ajax-call) and [Is there any reason to use a synchronous XMLHttpRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088318/is-there-any-reason-to-use-a-synchronous-xmlhttprequest)