# What exactly are web workers and when to use them

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was reading up something about XMLHttpRequest ([Is there any reason to use a synchronous XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088318/is-there-any-reason-to-use-a-synchronous-xmlhttprequest)) here on SO where I read on a thread from 2010 that, with the introduction of 'threads' in HTML5, developers might start to use synchronous APIs. Searching a bit on google, I found the MDN page on web workers.

I am writing Javascript and Node from about a year now (assume a beginner), and I am still to encounter something that makes use of these web workers. Maybe I need to read more code.

Now my question is, even though they seem to be very useful, why isn't it seen much in the wild? Also, what are the general use cases and guidelines when using them? Is it possible to reap the multithreaded processing benefits in Nodejs environment? If so, why are all Nodejs APIs still asynchronous?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web-worker is strictly a clientside thing, so it has nothing to do with Node.js (EDIT: actually, see [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads)).

You might have heard that JavaScript is strictly single-threaded: if a function is doing some heavy calculation, nothing else is getting done, including animating icons, repainting the window, nothing. Thus, clientside JS should always avoid heavy computation, large loops and anything else that might usurp the thread for more than a fraction of a second.

Web-workers are the solution for that. Each web-worker is running in its own thread, and it can block as much as it wants - it won't affect the normal operation of the web page. The tradeoff is that it cannot have any access to the DOM: the fact that it doesn't affect the rendering means you cannot affect rendering with it. :) If a web-worker wants to render something, it would have to send a message to the main thread to do it.

Implementation-wise, each web-worker needs to be in a separate JS file. The reason why you don't see more of them is probably twofold: the average Joe probably doesn't know how to use them, and they are only needed when you need serious computation and don't want it to block your main thread - which is not that common in the first place, and when it is, the computation is commonly offloaded to the server (on clientside) or to separate processes (in Node.js).

Read more on [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/).

Comment: That really answers all my queries. Thank you very much.